# MailPoet email composer removes post content HTML formatting

Tags: html, wordpress, newsletter

When using posts in the WordPress MailPoet email composer ((WordPress: 6.4.3, MailPoet: 4.46.0, MailPoetPremium: 4.46.0, PHP: 7.4.33), the original HTML formatting added in the original post content is removed by MailPoet – so originally italic or bold formatted text parts have to be re-formatted again in MailPoet. Is there a way to make MailPoet keep the original post content formatting?